# How to create several pages with dompdf

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dompdf

I am having some trouble with multidimensional array and its value.

What i am looking for is , from my query I am searching teachers name in the array. And after that i want to create a pdf using dompdf. The problem is with looping. I am not able to create a proper loop which will work the way I want it to work. My sample query is

```
    $q11 = "select id from teachers order by teacher ";
    $r11 = mysql_query($q11) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rows11 = mysql_fetch_array($r11)){
        $teacher = $rows11['id'];
        $dompdf->"It will start working";
    }
```

Now i know , this code is confusing, but what i want is, it should create dompdf for every teacher in one single pdf file. Like from the query it should fetch teachers, and for each teacher it should create a dompdf page. Currently it is making just one page according to the last value that my query has search.

Please help. It is kinda urgent.

Comment: I'd advise against using mysql_* functions for database access.  They're old, poorly supported and deprecated in all but name (and will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5).  I'd suggest switching to a more modern system such as mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Sounds like it is not a problem with  multidimensional array or loop but with proper `$dompdf` usage.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your loop is working fine. The way you add pages to your PDF is probably wrong. Apparently you are overwriting one page again and again instead of attaching a new one.

**EDIT**

I've never used dompdf. A quick look into the docs let me think you create something like a HTML markup which then is converted into PDF, did I get this right?

***Example code***

```
$html = <<<HTML
  <html>
      <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                /* Your document styling goes here */
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
HTML;

while ( $row = $dbResult->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $html .= '<div class="teacherPage">'
                 . $row['name'] // your teacher document goes here
             '</div>';
}

$html .= '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

If you wonder about the unusual syntax `$var = <<<HTML \r\nHTML`, that's a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's just more comfortable to use heredocs when you have a lot of alien inline code, this can have variables `{$varname}` and you don't need to worry about quotes. All you need to make sure, is that heredoc closer `HTML` is in a new line and not indented.

**EDIT2**

Still not too sure, which library you are using. I find [this extension](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage) looking pretty good and it's called dompdf, just like you said in your question.

Your latest comment indicates you did not solve your problem so far, so I decided to add some more information to get you to the target.

> *Disclaimer: I am not going to  write functional code and I will not test this, but the following hints will push you into the right direction to get your stuff done.*

dompdf is able to read CSS2 and CSS3 properties of your input document.

Each cycle in the `while` loop above represents one teacher whith each of them getting a own page in the output document.

I put the page into a div container with the class `teacherPage`. You can fill this container with all the information you want to have displayed for a teacher.

Now all we need to do, is to tell dompdf each `teacherPage` is a new page. This can be done using `@page` markup [shipped with CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)

I added an empty css container `<style type="text/css"></style>` to the example document above, that's where the page styling should go to.

**The example CSS**

```
@page teacher {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 2cm;
}

.teacherPage {
   page: teacher;
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

With `@page` you can define a named page `teacher`, which can have properties valid for the whole page container.

`page-break-after: always` will begin a new page after each container

Hope this helps, have fun trying :)

Comment: I guess thats right, but how can I stop it overwriting and go to the next page?

Comment: It should be explained in manual to whatever pdf library you are using.

Comment: added a css example for you, hope this helps

Comment: Excellent approach.. I also wanted to create multiple different forms under one Pdf to Print them together... This solution helped me in Dompdf.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently, no overflow problems and the results are taking more than the permitted margin of the sheet. What you can do is to separate data from the parent in another table and put between them:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```