# codeigniter generating multiple pdfs

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation, dompdf

i'm trying to generates pdfs in loop against member id, but every time i got only the first one, i addedd code in foreach so it runs multiple times, but it gives me only one pdf.please someone help me.

```
public function pdf($ids){

    $k = 0;
    foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {


    $data[$k]['academics'] =  $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table_where('member_academics', array('member_id' => $id));
    $data[$k]['member_employment'] =  $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table_where('member_employment', array('member_id' => $id));
    $data[$k]['member_data'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table_where('members',array('member_id' => $id));
    $data[$k]['disclosure'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('generalsettings',array('key'=>'disclosure'));
    $data[$k]['enrollment_fee'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('member_invoices',array('user_id' => $id,'paymentFor'=>'Enrollment Fee'));
    $data[$k]['enrollment_fee']['payment'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('member_payments',array('invoice_id'=>$data[$k]['enrollment_fee']['id']));

    $j=0;
    if (!empty($data[$k]['member_data'])) {
        foreach ($data[$k]['member_data'] as $member) {
            $data[$k]['member_data'][$j]['term'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('term', array('term_id' => $member['term_id']));
            $data[$k]['member_data'][$j]['degree'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('degree', array('degree_id' => $member['degree_id']));
             $data[$k]['member_data'][$j]['year'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('year', array('year_id' => $member['year_id']));
             $data[$k]['member_data'][$j]['address'] = $this->Utility_model->get_all_from_table('member_addresses', array('id' => $member['address_id']));

            $j++;
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/reports_management/applications_pdf/pdf_output',$data[$k],false);
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream($k."file".".pdf");
    $k++;   
    }
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($data);
    // die;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you wish to do. Do you want to show multiple pdf's on a single page?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only request the page once you cannot get the controller method to output more than one file. You could either try to instead make a multiple page PDF or you need to change how the controller is called, and call it multiple times.

See this answer for some input about making multiple page PDF: [How to create several pages with dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089883/how-to-create-several-pages-with-dompdf)