# Multiple pages with diferent orientation in Dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I want to create multiple pages, but each one with diferent orientation

```
1st page -> Potrait
2nd page -> Landscape
3rd page -> Potrait
4th page -> Potrait
....
```

With TCPDF will be easy to solve

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false); // create PDF
$pdf->AddPage('L', PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false); // Add page Landscape
$pdf->AddPage('P', PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false); // Add page Potrait
$pdf->AddPage('L', PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false); // Add page Landscape
....
```

With Dompdf and Laravel no idea how can I solve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot create one page at a time or append another page with DomPDF because it renders the whole layout at one time.

You have actually two options here:

- reate multiple single file pdf files using DomPDF and then join those using tools like `pdftk`
- Join all your view files together and wrap them inside a `div` with css property `page-break-after: always;` More info here [How to create several pages with dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089883/how-to-create-several-pages-with-dompdf)